# pdf streams in python

Tags: python, pdf

Why, when reading a pdf file into Python, do pdf stream objects terminate prematurely? Why can I open a pdf in Notepad, etc and have the entire file display fine, but not in Python? I am aware of pypdf, pdfminer, etc. This is purely to help me understand what's going on behind the scenes.

````
fp = open(r'E:Books\glu.pdf')
foo = fp.read()
print(foo)
%PDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
%header, xref, etc omitted for clarity.

34 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Catalog 
/Pages 31 0 R 
>> 
endobj
69 0 obj
<< /S 274 /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 70 0 R >> 
stream
Hﾉb```f``éb`c`àd`àc@
%Stream is much longer, but always terminates prematurely.
````

Comment: Mistake in first row:  fp = open(r'E:\Books\glu.pdf')

Comment: streams are binary. You should open the file in binary mode, but you cannot print them on a terminal.

Comment: I get that they're binary. I guess the question is-- is there a byte sequence that causes Python to terminate reading?

Comment: It works fine here. Check that the length of `foo` matches the file size.

Comment: Because the streams are binary, you should also open the file in binary mode, e.g. open(fname, 'rb')

Answer (score 0):

Open the pdf file in binary mode:

```
fp = open(r'E:Books\glu.pdf','rb')
foo = fp.read()
print(foo)

#and don't forget to close the file
fp.close()
```